# How to define model input and outputs in tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to create a model what should have nx8x8 input and 8x8 output or like below 64 units output, but don't know how to create it to make it work. I'm trying with the below code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

input = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(8,8), name='input')
model.add(input)

middle = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid',  name='a')
model.add(middle)

output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='softmax',  name='b')
model.add(output)
print(model.input_shape)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            metrics=['accuracy'])

train_input = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3],
        [3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0]
    ],
    [
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3],
        [3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0]
    ]
)
train_output = np.array([
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
    3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3,
    3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0,
])
model.fit(train_input, train_output, epochs=10)
```

What I'm doing bad? How to define input and outputs shape?

Comment: What error are you getting? The output shape is defined by the number of units in your last Dense layer

Comment: Also what are you trying to achieve with this model?

Comment: I updated output:
train_output = np.array([
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
    3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3,
    3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0,
])
error:

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 2
  y sizes: 64
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Comment: I want to train something with input 8x8 and get output 8x8 or 64 elements (like get train_input some 8x8 checkers map and get in output what move should be so like return 8x8 map, but I couldn't set 8x8 so I used 64 units in output)

Comment: Can you tell me the shape of the train input and output?

Comment: train input: 2x8x8 (but 2 will be changing depending on how many moves will be possible) train output: 64 elements in a list

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more instance to your `train_output`. You have two samples on your `train_input` but only one label. You need the same amount of labels as instances of input. This solves your cardinality issue.

However your data is formatted in a very strange way, I'm pretty sure you will have more issues when training. You're doing a classification task but your labels are not enconded as they should. You should enconde your labels into classes (e.g 0,1,2) and then your model will only output a classification.

Comment: Now i have error:
UserWarning: "`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received `from_logits=True`, but the `output` argument was produced by a sigmoid or softmax activation and thus does not represent logits. Was this intended?"

Comment: Remove from_logits=True, you have the softmax activation function on the last Dense layer so you don't need from_logits

Comment: I tried remove from_logits, but still had the same issue.

Comment: What is the error message now?